# why is JSONP not need here?

Tags: jquery, json

Im just trying to wrap my head round JSON/JSONP and cross domain issues.

Heres an example I found.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var user = "jamesbarnett"; //treehouse username

  /* get treehouse profile info via JSON */
  $.getJSON("https://teamtreehouse.com/" + user + ".json", function(data) { 
    console.log(data);// intialize list
    $("#badges").html('<ol>');
    var output = "";
    /* loop through the JSON, parse out badge name & icon
    wrap it in some HTML. */    
    for (var i in data.badges) {
        output += "<li>";
        output +="<figure>";
        output +="<figcaption>" + data.badges[i].name + "</figcaption>";
        output += "<img src = '" + data.badges[i].icon_url + "'/>";
        output+="</figure>";
        output += "</li>";    
    }
    $("#badges ol").append(output); // append li
    $("#badges ol").append('</ol>'); // close list

    /* hide spinner and then output HTML we built in the for loop */
    $(".spinner").hide();
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/oHsvr

Can someone please explain why, in this example there is *no* cross domain issues (and the person has not needed to use JSONP)

Since the data comes from Treehouse domain...and is being displayed on codepen.io.... is this not a cross-domain?

Comment: Presumably because the response from `teamtreehouse.com` domain includes CORS headers that allow the request to come from the required domain

Comment: Also note for reference that JSON and JSONP are not interchangeable. You have to use what the endpoint gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a response of `curl -v https://teamtreehouse.com/jamesbarnett.json`:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
... Response truncated for brevity ...
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
< ETag: W/"497006ef8221ce12b09998c0cdee8153"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
... Response truncated for brevity ...
```

Notice `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. This means that they allow any domain to send XHR request. Hence, no CORS error.

Comment: Thanks Piyush. So any site can configure (on their end) whether or not CORS can be allowed?  I wasnt aware. Cheers